# how can I display ultimate member plugin's input meta fields on WordPress admin panel edit account page for editing by the admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, ultimate-member

I am using the plugin "Ultimate Member" for WordPress, It is working fine... I want some additional functionality where the admin has the ability to change certain data (like gender, occupation, country, etc.) from the admin panel (edit user page). With some help from some blog posts I put together some code which is able to display edit fields of the relevant/target user on the edit account page.

The issue is that certain fields like gender and country are not showing their current values and none of the fields update when the "user button" is clicked.

[image: these are the custom meta fields displayed in the edit account page]

Here is the code I used on ./wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/functions.php  :

```
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'showUMExtraFields', 100);

function showUMExtraFields()
{
    ob_start();

    $id = um_user('ID');
    $output = '<div class="um-field">';
    $names = array("user_login", 'birth_date', "gender", "country", "user_url", "cool_input");  // the meta names of the feilds I want to display

    $fields = array();
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $fields[$name] = UM()->builtin()->get_specific_field($name);
    }
    $fields = apply_filters('um_account_secure_fields', $fields, $id);
    foreach ($fields as $key => $data) {
        $output .= UM()->fields()->edit_field($key, $data);
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $output;
}

add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'getUMFormData');

function getUMFormData()
{
    $id = um_user('ID');
    $names = array("user_login", 'birth_date', "gender", "country", "user_url", "cool_input");  // the meta names of the feilds I want to display

    foreach ($names as $name) {
        if (!empty($secure_fields)) {
            update_user_meta($id, $name, $_POST[$name]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to display select boxes from Ultimate Member in another form/page. I came up with a solution... but it still isn't good enough, it doesn't update the select boxes...

```
//fields that you want to display... meta_keys
function custom_feild_meta(){
    return $feild_meta = array("first_name", 'last_name', "GrandFather_Name", "Brach_Name", "Family_Name", "Family_Name_41",  "mobile_number_38", "user_email", "mobile_number", "Secondary_System", "mobile_number_38_37_37", "mobile_number_38_37", "mobile_number_38_37_37_37", "Guardian_Name", "phone_number", "country", "City_26_27_29_30_31_32_33_34_35_36", "City_26", "City", "City_26_27_29", "City_26_27", "City_26_27_29_30_31", "City_26_27_29_30_31_32", "City_26_27_29_30", "City_26_27_29_30_31_32_33", "City_26_27_29_30_31_32_33_34", "City_26_27_29_30_31_32_33_34_35", "City_26_27_28", "City_26_27_29_30_31_32_33_34_35_36_37", "Note_42");  //feilds feilds meta name to display
}


//display fields
function showUMExtraFields()
{

    
    print('<h3>Extra profile information</h3>');
    
    ob_start();
    

    $id = um_user('ID');
    // $id = UM()->user()->target_id;
    $output = '<div class="um-field">';
    $tame;
    $names = custom_feild_meta();  
    
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $fields[$name] = UM()->builtin()->get_specific_field($name);
    }
    $fields = apply_filters('um_account_secure_fields', $fields, $id);
    foreach ($fields as $key => $data) {
        
        //if it is a select box
        if($data['type'] == 'select'){
            
            $select_value = get_user_meta( $id, $key)[0];
            $select_title =  $data['title'];
            $select_meta_key = $data['metakey'];
            
            
             $output .= "<div id='um_field__$key' class='um-field um-field-select  um-field-$key um-field-select um-field-type_select' data-key='$key'> <div class='um-field-label'> <label for='$key'>$select_title</label> <div class='um-clear'></div> </div> <div class='um-field-area  '> <select data-default='$value' name='$select_meta_key' id='$key' data-validate='' data-key='$key' class='um-form-field valid um-s1 ' style='width: 100%'>";
             
             foreach($data['options'] as $option){
                 $output .= "<option value='$option' ($option == $select_value ? 'selected' : '')>$option</option>";
             }

             $output .= "</select> </div> </div>";  
        }else{
            //if not a select box (the default way)
            $output .= UM()->fields()->edit_field($key, $data);         
        }       
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $output;
    echo $tame;
}


//update/save field date, works only for default fields not select boxes
function getUMFormData($user_id)
{
    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id))
        return false;

    $meta_number = 0;
    $custom_meta_fields = custom_feild_meta();
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name) {
        $meta_number++;
        update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_field_name, $_POST[$meta_field_name]);
    }
}


add_action('show_user_profile', 'showUMExtraFields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'showUMExtraFields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'getUMFormData');
add_action('personal_options_update', 'getUMFormData');
```

Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur if it's right. I expanded your code to use for checkboxes, and seems ok

```
//display fields
function showUMExtraFields()
{
    ob_start();
    
    //Only reading $disable = "disabled", else leave just ""
    $disable = "disabled";

    $id = um_user('ID');
    // $id = UM()->user()->target_id;
    $output = '<table class="form-table">';
    $output = $output.'<tr><th><label>Extra profile information</label></th>';
    $tame;
    $names = custom_feild_meta();  
    
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $fields[$name] = UM()->builtin()->get_specific_field($name);
    }
    $fields = apply_filters('um_account_secure_fields', $fields, $id);
    foreach ($fields as $key => $data) {
        
        //if it is a select box
        if($data['type'] == 'select'){
            
            $select_value = get_user_meta( $id, $key)[0];
            $select_title =  $data['title'];
            $select_meta_key = $data['metakey'];
            
             $output .= 
             "<td>
                <span class='um-field um-field-select um-field-$key um-field-select um-field-type_select' data-key='$key'>$select_title:</span>
                    <div class='um-field-label'> 
                        <label for='$key'></label>
                        <div class='um-clear'></div> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class='um-field-area  '> 
                        <select data-default='$value' name='$select_meta_key' id='$key' data-validate='' data-key='$key' class='um-form-field valid um-s1 ' style='width: 100%'>";
             
             foreach($data['options'] as $option){
                 $output .= "<option value='$option' ($option == $select_value ? 'selected' : '')>$option</option>";
             }

             $output .= "</select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>";
        
        //if it is a checkbox
        }elseif($data['type'] == 'checkbox') {
        
            $check_value = get_user_meta( $id, $key)[0];
            $check_title =  $data['title'];
            $check_meta_key = $data['metakey'];
            $output .= 
            "
                <td>
                    <span class='usergroup-category-name'>$check_title</span><br/>";
            foreach($data['options'] as $option){
                $output .="<input name='$key"."[]' id='$key"."-$option' type='checkbox' value='$option'";
                if  (in_array($option, $check_value)){
                    $output .='checked="checked"';}
                $output .= $disable."/> <label>$option </label><br/>";
            }
            $output .= "</td>";  
         }else{
            //if not a select box (the default way)
            $output .= UM()->fields()->edit_field($key, $data);         
        }       
    }

    $output .= '<tr></table>';

    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $output;
    echo $tame;
}


//update/save field date, works only for default fields not select boxes
function getUMFormData($user_id)
{
    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id))
        return false;

    $meta_number = 0;
    $custom_meta_fields = custom_feild_meta();
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name) {
        $meta_number++;
        update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_field_name, $_POST[$meta_field_name]);
    }
}


add_action('show_user_profile', 'showUMExtraFields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'showUMExtraFields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'getUMFormData');
add_action('personal_options_update', 'getUMFormData');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).